# Unpacking array of objects into function arguments in Julia

Tags: julia

How do you unpack array of values into function arguments?

For example, function `Iterators.product()` takes variable number of iterators as arguments, i.e.

```
collect(Iterators.product(1:2, 3:5))
  2×3 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
   (1, 3)  (1, 4)  (1, 5)
   (2, 3)  (2, 4)  (2, 5)
```

Given an array of iterators, such as `a=[1:2, 3:5]`, how do you unpack `a` without manually accessing it's elements with `a[1]` (for example, when length of `a` is not known in advance)?

I am hoping there is something like the asterisk operator in Python, (something like `Iterators.product(*a)`), but I didn't find anything like that yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/unpack-arguments-from-an-array-into-function/29656), instead of `fun(*arr)`, use `fun(arr...)`.

Comment: It is named the "splat" operator. From [the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/): The "splat" operator, `...`, represents a sequence of arguments. `...` can be used in function definitions, to indicate that the function accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. `...` can also be used to apply a function to a sequence of arguments.